Notation of Expected value, when game with loss function and strategy as variable.
I have the case where I need to write the expected value of a score  $\mathbb{E}[S]$ in a game where we can use different strategies $\sigma$ and also the loss function $f$ may change, which I write like this.
$\mathbb{E}[S | \sigma, f]$ where $S$ is given by a score function $f(n)$ and some other variables of the game.
In the paper i work with this expression a lot, like adding other constrains:
$$\mathbb{E}[S | \sigma, f, n=n_1] = \mathbb{E}[S | \sigma, f, n=n_2] + \mathbb{E}[S | \sigma, f, n=n_3]$$
Is it normal or advisable to shorten this notation? and what would be a good way of doing it?
Maybe $\mathbb{E}_{f \sigma}$  I guess the score $S$ is somewhat implicit. But then how to put the new constrains:
$$\mathbb{E}_{f \sigma}[S|n=n_1]\text{ or }\mathbb{E}_{\sigma}[f(n) |n=n_1]$$
Other possibility is define a function. $\mathbb{E}[S | \sigma, f] = g(\dots)$ and add constrains by putting them in the function  $g(n=n_1)$.
